# Sending data over MultiPath TCP

Tags: tcp, tcpclient

After installing MPTCP on my two debian hosts, I would like to know how can I send data using MultiPath TCP.

Thank you

Comment: It would be nice to know how to do this on other OSes like OS X.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you rebooted with the mptcp kernels (sysctl -a|grep mptcp should return a few results) and then contact (via iperf for instance) an mptcp enabled server such as http://multipath-tcp.org.
You should then be able to see the number of created TCP subflows via cat /proc/net/mptcp.