# Multipath TCP : Multiple connections Not Showing

Tags: linux, tcp, linux-kernel, network-programming

I installed the mptcp kernel on my machine. I tried to test MPTCP by running iperf -c multipath-tcp.org (both end-ponts are MPTCP CAPABLE).
I tried to test if iperf lists the subflows created. I have an active wifi interface + active wired interface. But still iperf showed only the one with the wired interface:

```
Client connecting to multipath-tcp.org, TCP port 5001
TCP window size: 45.0 KByte (default)
------------------------------------------------------------
[  3] local 192.168.42.123 port 52983 connected with 130.104.230.45 port 5001
[ ID] Interval       Transfer     Bandwidth
[  3]  0.0-22.7 sec   384 KBytes   139 Kbits/sec
```

THis shouldn't be the case. My wired link was too slow so, even if the flow would have started here, surely subflow would be there in the wifi interface as well.

How could I actually see that MPTCP is in fact creating subflows ?

I saw the [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21701397/sending-data-over-multipath-tcp) but my cat proc...  file is showing

```
  sl  loc_tok  rem_tok  v6 local_address                         remote_address                        st ns tx_queue rx_queue inode
   0: B491F32C CDF952DC  0 0B2BA8C0:8E9C                         2DE66882:1389                         01 02 00000000:00000000 203077
```

which doesn't relate to any subflows I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can check the mptcp setting with sysctl net.mptcp,the path manager should be setted to fullmesh rather than default to establish multiple flows.
sysctl -w net.mptcp.mptcp_path_manager=fullmesh
sysctl -w net.mptcp.mptcp_enabled=1
Further explanation of mptcp setting can be viewed at http://multipath-tcp.org/pmwiki.php/Users/ConfigureMPTCP